# Using identity theorem when functions and their derivatives agree on a point.

Tags: complex-analysis

I wanted to prove the following.

> Let $D\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a disk around some point $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$,  $f,g:D\to \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic and injective such that $f(D)=g(D)$, $f(z_0)=g(z_0)$ and $f'(z_0)=g'(z_0)$. Then $f=g$.

I thought about finding some sequence in $D$ such that $f,g$ agree on the sequence (I don't need to worry about convergence since $D$ is bounded), but I don't really know where to start.

Also, although we haven't arrived to the [Schwarz Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) yet, I think it might be of some use.

So, if possible, how can the identity theorem and/or Schwarz lemma be used to solve this? And if not possible, which other ways are there?

Comment: Wait if they agree on $D$ doesn't that imply the existance of an accumulation point and thus the identity theorem?

Comment: They don't agree on $D$. $D$ has the same image under both functions.

Comment: Ah ok now it makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality we may suppose that $D$ is the unit circle, and $z_0=0$, let $U=f(D)$. $g:D\to U$ is holomorphic and [univalent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univalent_function) so it is biholomorphic, i.e. it is invertible and its inverse $g^{-1}:U\to D$ is holomorphic. So, $h=g^{-1}\circ f:D\to D$ is holomorphic, and satisfies $h(0)=0$ and $h’(0)=1$. This, implies by [Schwarz lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) that $h(z)=z$ for all $z$ in $D$. That is $g=f$. Done.

Comment: It seems straightforward, then, by Schwarz Lemma. Thanks.